# Read server streaming into client c#

Tags: c#, grpc, grpc-dotnet, grpc-c#

I'm doing an application using server streaming.

The problem is the client doesn't read the data from the server streaming.

This is my `proto` service:

```sh
service UserService {
    rpc GetData(Id) returns (stream DataResponse) {}
}
message Id {
    int32 id = 1;
}

message DataResponse {
    bytes data = 1;
}
```

c# server is like this:

```cs
public override async Task GetData(Id request, IServerStreamWriter<DataResponse> response, ServerCallContext context)
{
    var user = {} // get user
    foreach (var d in user.Data)
    {
        await response.WriteAsync(new DataResponse { Data = d });
    }
}
```

And it works because I have a NodeJS client where I can call the server and works perfectly.

Client in Node is

```js
let call = client.getData({id:1})
call.on('data', function (response) {
    // do things
})
call.on('end', function () {
    // do things
})
```

And c# client is:

```cs
AsyncServerStreamingCall<DataResponse> response = client.GetData(new Id{Id_ = 1});
while(await response.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Into while loop"); // <-- This is never executed
    DataResponse current = response.ResponseStream.Current;
    Console.WriteLine($"{current.Data}");
}
```

I've also added a `try/catch` and it doesn't output anything so it seems `MoveNext()` is always `false`.

What is the problem here? Why NodeJS client works and c# client can't read the stream? Have I missed something?

Here is full client.cs class:

```cs
class Program
{
    const int Port = 50051;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Channel channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1:50051", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
            var client = new UserService.UserServiceClient(channel);
            GetDataStreaming(client);
        }
        catch (RpcException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {{Code: {ex.StatusCode}, Status: {ex.Status.Detail}}}");
        }
    }

    private static async void GetDataStreaming(UserService.UserServiceClient client)
    {
        
            AsyncServerStreamingCall<DataResponse> response = client.GetData(new Id { Id_ = 1 });
            while (await response.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Into while loop");
                DataResponse current = response.ResponseStream.Current;
                Console.WriteLine($"{current.Data.ToStringUtf8()}");
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Cannnot reproduce the issue. It works fine for me. Does host name and port match between the server and the client?

Comment: Yes. Server receive both calls, from c# and NodeJS clients. Also I've tried another client (NodeJS client) and works ok. The connection is the same, the server is up and should works but... The problem is c# client but I cannot find what happen.

Comment: Do you use the both clients at the same time? Could you share the whole code of C# client?

Comment: No, the use of NodeJS client was only to test if c# server works correctly, but I only use one client (c# client). I've also updated the question to show the client class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your client has ended before the client receive the response. When you call `GetDataStreaming(client)` in `Main` it doesn't wait and finishes.

To fix the issue change `async void GetDataStreaming` to `async Task GetDataStreaming`.

```
private static async Task GetDataStreaming(UserService.UserServiceClient client)
{        
        AsyncServerStreamingCall<DataResponse> response = client.GetData(new Id { Id_ = 1 });
        while (await response.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Into while loop");
            DataResponse current = response.ResponseStream.Current;
            Console.WriteLine($"{current.Data.ToStringUtf8()}");
        }
}
```

Change `static void Main` to `static async Task Main` and you should also call `channel.ShutdownAsync` method at the end.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Channel channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1:50051", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
        var client = new UserService.UserServiceClient(channel);
        await GetDataStreaming(client);
        await channel.ShutdownAsync();
    }
    catch (RpcException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {{Code: {ex.StatusCode}, Status: {ex.Status.Detail}}}");
    }
}
```

Another option is to change `async void GetDataStreaming` to `async Task GetDataStreaming` and in `Main` method wait until `Task` complete.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Channel channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1:50051", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
        var client = new UserService.UserServiceClient(channel);
        var task = GetDataStreaming(client);
        task.Wait();
    }
    catch (RpcException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {{Code: {ex.StatusCode}, Status: {ex.Status.Detail}}}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! That was the problem, thank you so much.

Comment: Why should you also call `await channel.ShutdownAsync();` at the end?  I think you should call, at the end of GetDataStreaming, response.GetStatus() and check that it is OK.  If its not OK, you may want to throw an exception, as it could indicate you did not process the fulll result - it depends whether the overall process can be resumed based on process safety for progress/preservation program safety properties